# Remove inApp purchase after rejection

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I had submitted the application on iTunes.It has some problem with inApp purchase.
So the binary got rejected.

The inApp :- Nonconsumable

now i had remove the inApp functionality from  the application.
How can i disable the inApp from the itunes.
I remember there is one Tickmark option for inApp in metadata..
Which i had selected..But now it is not appearing..

Comment: I think you should try to solve the issue instead of give up!!! What was the reason of rejection can you please write here it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your in app purchase and then upload new binary.
Steps to delete in AppPurchase

```
 1. Login to intunesconnect.
 2. Manage Application.
 3. Select your app.
 4. Manage Inapp purchase.
 5. Select in app purchase already created.
 6. Delete it.
```

Now click ready to upload binary, and upload your binary to store.

Comment: i had done the developer binary rejection.But not able to see the delete button for the product and there is no check box.BY inApp is showing inReview status only

Comment: Do you followed teh steps? Once you enter manage inApppurchse section, you have to click on your inapppurchase to view its detail.Then there is delete option on the top left.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps I believe you should take.

1- Upload a new binary

2- Reject the binary yourself

3- delete in-app purchase items

4- mark the app ready for upload

5- upload a new build without the in-app purchase code

Comment: This is how I do it. iTunes does not allow you to modify in-app purchases items on iTunes connect site because you marked your app ready for upload. to get it to the old state use the trick I posted above.

Comment: delete the inApp purchase item means? the deleting the inApp product? by deleting the inApp purchase does the inApp get disable?

Comment: no, but you are still add more in-app consumable or non consumable products later.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will have to create a new application on iTunes store with out having in-App feature configured to it.

Comment: i cannot upload it by doing it same way?

Comment: You can delete in-App purchases and upload the new binary.

Comment: I had deleted the inApp pruchase from code.NOw from where i delete the inApp from intunes? Should i have to delete the inApp product?

Comment: yes @shweta i have gine you documentation, which has screenshot how remove inApp product for manage purchase section